# where does v.end() point to?

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, sequence

```
for (vector<Student_info>::const_iterator iter = students.begin();
     iter != students.end(); ++iter)
    cout << (*iter).name << endl;
```

In Accelerated C++, code above was told to output all of the data contain in the vector, but if the loop stop when `iter != students.end()` equal to `students.end()`, then how does it will proceed to the last element of the vector?

Comment: I don't know what "how does it will proceed to the last element of the vector?" means

Comment: Given `std::vector<T> v`, `*(v.end()) == v[v.size()];` (Note: actual attempts to dereference is UB).

Comment: The nice result of the current definition is that for an empty container (and _only_ for empty containers), `v.begin()==v.end()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood well what you asked,it is so because the last element of a vector is actually on the position v.end()-1. So to an element before the v.end() should the loop stop to access all the elements. Is that you asked?

Comment: thought so other answers understandable, I prefer this one for its mathematical equation, well, It's my fault for thinking that last element of vector equal to v.end(), anyway, thnx everyone ^_^

Comment: @Vastor: But you should know that that *mathematical equation* is not correct for all kind of iterators. That is why I, and many others, didn't write that. Everyone explained this in words which is correct for all kind of iterators.

Answer (score 4):

`end()` points to somewhere past the end of the container. By convention, sequences in C++ are of the form `[begin, end)`, that is, the end is *not* part of the sequence. For arrays and vectors, `end()` points to the index equal to the size of the array (which is outside the array or vector).

This convenient in many aspects. For an empty sequence, for instance, the begin and end of the container are the same element. Also, the value returned by `end()` is commonly used as an "invalid" iterator, as it does not point to a meaningful element.

Answer (score 3):

The loop you have written is roughly equivalent to:

```
vector<Student_info>::const_iterator iter = students.begin();
while (iter != students.end()) {
    cout << (*iter).name << endl;
    ++iter;
}
```

This is the normal expansion of the `for` loop into its `while` equivalent<sup>1</sup>. Every time through the loop, the `iter` iterator is incremented (with `++iter`) to advance to the next element. When the end of the vector is reached, then `iter` will equal `students.end()` and the loop will exit.

<sup>1. Except for the scope of `iter` remains within the body of the `for` loop.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

`end()` returns a special value that means "iteration ended, stop". Usually that's an iterator to the element beyond the array end - you don't have to process it, you should stop once you reached it and that's what the loop does.

Comment: By definition, `end()` returns an iterator "one past the last element"; in other words, if an iterator designates the last element, incrementing it causes it to be equal to `end()`.  But this is really simply a way of describing it; you can't really say what the `end()` points to, since it doesn't point to anything; you can't dereference it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `.end()` does not return the iterator to the *last* element, rather it returns iterator to *past-the-last-element*.  The iterator to the last element is just before it; that is, if `it` points to the last element, then `++it` makes `it` to point to past-the-last-element.

The language specification calls it *past-the-end* iterator.

§24.1/5 (C++03) reads,

> Just as a regular pointer to an array guarantees that there is a pointer value pointing past the last element of the array, so for any iterator type there is an iterator value that points past the last element of a corresponding container. These values are called past-the-end values. Values of an iterator i for which the expression *i is defined are called dereferenceable. The library never assumes that past-the-end values are dereferenceable

Also note that *dereferencing* the past-the-end iterator invokes undefined behavior:

```
auto it = students.end(); //ok
it->someFunction();       //undefined behavior
(*it).someFunction();     //undefined behavior
```